# How to store multiple JavaScript objects from a file to a variable

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

So this how the app should work: with a Node.js script I call the [coincap.io api](https://github.com/CoinCapDev/CoinCap.io), and I store the response of the various request in different files. Here is the script:

```
var request = require("request");
var fs = require("fs");
var cors = require("cors");
var parseString = require("xml2js").parseString;
var coinstore = [];
var endpoint = ["coins", "map", "front", "global"];

for (i = 0; i < endpoint.length; i++) {
    request("http://coincap.io/" + endpoint[i], function(err, response, body) {
        console.log("error", Error);
        console.log("statusCode: ", response && response.statusCode);
        //console.log("body: ", JSON.stringify(body));
        var xml = body;
        parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
            console.log(xml);
            coinstore.push(xml);
        });

        fs.writeFile("D:/bibblebit/response" + response.request.path.replace(/\//g, "") + ".json", coinstore,
            function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("salvato!");
                }
            });
    });
};
```

I then let the user make custom calls and retrieve data from those files.

Here is a working call:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log("pronto!");
        var alldata = [];
        alldata.push(xhr.response);
        var obj = JSON.parse(alldata);
        console.log(obj);

        document.getElementById("api-container").innerHTML += obj.altCap;
    } else {
        console.log("try again");
    }
}

xhr.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8081/responseglobal.json", true);
xhr.send(null);
```

This works because the file responseglobal.json has a single object.

Changing the last snippet into this one:

```
        document.getElementById("api-container").innerHTML += obj.mktcap;
    }
    else {
        console.log("try again");
    }
}

xhr.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8081/responsefront.json", true);
xhr.send(null);
```

returns a self explanatory error:

> [Visualizza/nascondi dettagli messaggio.] SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 264 of the JSON data

Every comma separating objects results in an unexpected character, which means I am not able to create one object for every object in the file or at least read a file with more than one object. What am I missing?

I may have missed the right approach. I can't find on the net a fitting explanation, since the questions I was able to find refer to manually created objects or so specific scenarios to become useless in my case to a different extent.

Comment: Thank you for the revision i was going to edit the question but you did it for me so double thank you :D can you help me with my issue also?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you're trying to do. For instance, you're doing a bunch of overlapping requests, and pushing their results into a single array, and outputting that array (the entire thing) repeatedly to different files. Aside from the fact the requests could complete in any order, it's not clear why you're outputting the full array to each individual file...

Comment: (Side note: Your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). You need to declare `i` at the very least, possibly others.)

Comment: I really don't get it. It's clear that i am at my very first interactions with js behaviour and i don't clearly understand asynchronous programming. Said that, for what i know your task is not judging me if you don't want to help me improve my understanding it was better to delete my question or simply don't reply.... what you said is totally true and fair but far from helping me. Thank you anyway for your time

Comment: I don't understand your complaint. I'm not judging you, and I've done a lot to try to help you. I've politely (I hope!) let you know that posting poorly-formatted, hard-to-read code makes it hard for people to help you -- and I've improved your question by formatting the code for you. I've tried to understand your question so I could answer it, and asked you relevant questions when I couldn't understand it (which you haven't answered). I've also helpfully pointed out an error I saw in the code (as a comment, because I don't think it's the main issue). What exactly was unhelpful?

Comment: I don't see your relevant questions. For the revision i have already said i am thankful (this helped me for further questions but not a lot for now). You said "it's not clear why you're outputting the full array to each individual file... " and since the output and the creation of the files seems ok i haven't understood what is the problem (so this helped me very little) declaring i was the only thing i got. On top of that your approach while responding may have discouraged others to reply since the code (as you pointed out) is wrong in its foundation.

Comment: If by relevant question you meant "It's not at all clear to me what you're trying to do" i am trying to input let's say mktcap on the site and get the value of mktcap attribute from every object in the .json file. sorry i was unclear

Comment: "It's not clear" is a clear request for clarification. Why are you outputting the full array each time? Is that intentional? If so, what is your goal? If not intentional, then that may be part of the problem. The more thorough and complete your explanation is, the more likely you are to get helpful answers. Hopefully someone else can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the server side script:

```
var request = require("request");
var fs = require("fs");
var cors = require ("cors");
var parseString = require("xml2js").parseString;
var endpoint = ["coins", "map","front", "global"];
var i = 0;

for (i=0 ; i<endpoint.length ; i++){
    request("http://coincap.io/"+endpoint[i], function (err, response, body){

        var coinstore = [];
        console.log("error", Error);
        console.log("statusCode: ", response && response.statusCode);

        var xml =JSON.stringify(body);
        parseString(xml, function (err, result){
            console.log(xml);
            coinstore.push(xml);
        });

        fs.writeFileSync("/response"+ response.request.path.replace(/\//g, "")+ ".json", coinstore, function(err){
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("salvato!");
            }
        });
    });
};
```

And this one is the client-side one:

```
var queries = [ "global", "coins", "map","front"];
for(i=0; i<queries.length; i++) {
    pronto(i);
}

function pronto(i) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            console.log("pronto!");
            var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
            //console.log(obj);
            document.getElementById("api"+i+"-container").innerHTML+=obj;
            console.log("stampato: "+ i);
        } else {
            console.log("bucato");
        }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", "response"+ queries[i] +".json", true);
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

They might not be the best solutions, but they work out.